# i want to change layout in livewire component but layout method is not working

Tags: layout, laravel-livewire

im using layout method to change layout in component but layout method not working.

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire. show-posts')
            ->layout('layouts. base');
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but could it be the spaces you have` Try `->layout('layouts.base')`

Comment: spaces doesn't matter. I've solved it by replacing layout to extends method.

Comment: Ah, that means that you are using `extend` and `section` rather than `layout` and `slot`, which is the "oldschool" way of doing things in Blade views. Glad to hear you figured it out none the less. For reference, here's the docs on that https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#custom-layout

Answer (score 0):

just replace layout method with extends method and it will work.

`view('livewire. show-posts')->extends('layouts. base');`